# select2 is not working in mobile collapse view of data table

Tags: datatable, datatables, resize, jquery-select2

Select2 is not working inside the datatable when i resize the window to mobile view. when i resize datatable is collapsed. When i expand the feild select2 is visible but when i click it is not showing the option.
I have tried fnDrawCallback(),drawCallback() inside the datatable initialisation. But not able to reslove the issue

```
var DatTable = $('#tblRoleMap').DataTable( {
        "autoWidth": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        drawCallback: function() {
            $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
            placeholder: "Select Role",
            allowClear: true
            });
        }
    } );
```